# Remove correlated sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

Could you please help me to optimize the query. we are using correlated sub queries to resolve our problem. How to improve the performance and remove the correlated sub-query.

```
SELECT CAST((CASE WHEN value = 1
  THEN CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(records)
                  FROM ABC
                  WHERE ABC.ID = XYZ.ID) > 0
    THEN 1
       ELSE 0 END
             ELSE CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(records)
                             FROM PQR
                             WHERE PQR.ID = XYZ.ID) > 0
               THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 END END) AS AA) AS COLUMN FROM XYZ
```

Comment: Could you possibly give some sample input data and required output - it will help understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Correlated subqueries are not necessarily slow. They can even be the fastest method in some situations. As shown in Arth's answer it is `EXISTS` however you should use, not `COUNT`. To make this uncorrelated, you could use `IN` instead, but as mentioned, this doesn't necessarily mean the query becomes faster; it can even become slower. In any way make sure to have indexes on the columns in question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. I've moved subqueries to separated temp tables.

```
SELECT XYZ.id, 
        CASE WHEN XYZ.value = 1
             THEN CASE WHEN T.cnt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             ELSE CASE WHEN T2.cnt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             END as column
FROM XYZ
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ABC 
                GROUP BY id) AS T ON XYZ.id = T.id
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM PQR
                GROUP BY id) AS T2 ON XYZ.id = T2.id
GROUP BY XYZ.id
```

Another solution. Simply check existence id's in the tables ABC and PQR. Thanks to commentators.

```
SELECT XYZ.id,
       CASE WHEN XYZ.value = 1
            THEN T.id IS NOT NULL
            ELSE T2.id IS NOT NULL
            END AS column
FROM XYZ
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ABC) AS T ON XYZ.id = T.id
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM PQR) AS T2 ON XYZ.id = T2.id
```

Comment: This query may take more time as it contains more `group by` and join as compare to the OP posted.

Comment: Not sure you need the xyz.id in the select columns, or the group by clause on the outer query.

Comment: No need to group by ID and count in the subqueries. You can simply `select distinct id` and check for `t.id is not null` and `t2.id is not null` then. That should be much faster for being less work for the DBMS.

Comment: You can remove the inner cases: `CASE WHEN T.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` is the same as `T.id IS NOT NULL`..at least in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You should try and avoid using `COUNT` here, you don't care how many rows there are in each case, just whether they `EXIST` or not.

Boolean conditions in MySQL return `1` or `0` for `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively, so you can save yourself quite a bit of syntax.

I think this is what you want, heavily simplified:

```
SELECT (x.value  =1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABC a WHERE a.id = x.id))
         OR 
       (x.value !=1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PQR p WHERE p.id = x.id)) column
  FROM XYZ x
```

or possibly:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABC a WHERE a.id = x.id) column
  FROM XYZ x
 WHERE x.value = 1
 UNION ALL
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PQR p WHERE p.id = x.id)
  FROM XYZ x
 WHERE x.value != 1
```

or if you love case:

```
   SELECT CASE 
            WHEN x.value = 1 THEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ABC a WHERE a.id = x.id)
            ELSE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PQR p WHERE p.id = x.id)
          END column
     FROM XYZ x
```